# Correct way to close WCF 4 channels effectively

Tags: c#, wcf, idisposable, wcf-4

I am using the following ways to close the WCF 4 channels. Is this right way to do it?

```
using (IService channel 
    = CustomChannelFactory<IService>.CreateConfigurationChannel())
{
    channel.Open();

    //do stuff
}// channels disposes off??
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although not strictly directed at the channel, you can do:

```
ChannelFactory<IMyService> channelFactory = null;
try
{
    channelFactory =
        new ChannelFactory<IMyService>();
    channelFactory.Open();

    // Do work...

    channelFactory.Close();
}
catch (CommunicationException)
{
    if (channelFactory != null)
    {
        channelFactory.Abort();
    }
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
    if (channelFactory != null)
    {
        channelFactory.Abort();
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    if (channelFactory != null)
    {
        channelFactory.Abort();
    }
    throw;
}
```

Comment: This response is a bit off: it provides a usage pattern for the ChannelFactory, while the original question involves the channel.  While it is true (I believe) that closing the factory will close all the channels that it created, a more common pattern is to keep a channelFactory open so that it can create multiple channels efficiently.  Each channel should be individually closed while keeping the factory open for work.

Comment: That is true - thank you for pointing that out. Have adjusted post to reflect

Answer (score 26):

That *used to be* the commonly accepted way to release WCF client proxies in the "early" days of WCF.

However things have since changed. It turned out that the implementation of [IClientChannel<T>.Dispose()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) simply invokes the [IClientChannel<T>.Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195520.aspx) method, which **may throw an exception** under some circumstances, such as when the underlying channel isn't open or can't be closed in a timely fashion.

Therefore it's not a good idea to invoke `Close()` within a `catch` block since that may leave behind some unreleased resources in case of an exception.

The *new* recommended way is to invoke [IClientChannel<T>.Abort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.icommunicationobject.abort.aspx) within the `catch` block instead, in case `Close()` would fail. Here's an example:

```
try
{
    channel.DoSomething();
    channel.Close();
}
catch
{
    channel.Abort();
    throw;
}
```

**Update:**

Here's a reference to an MSDN article that [describes this recommendation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx).

Comment: Do I really have to close the channel? I am thinking to leave it open and next time I use it I check if factory.State != CommunicationState.Opened (pipe factory in my case) and if true then recreating channel.

Comment: @Valentin The short answer is **yes**, you *should* release a WCF channel *explicitly* when it is no longer needed. An open WCF channel holds some lower level resoures, such as a TCP socket or an HTTP connection. If you delay the release of these resources by leaving it in the *nondeterministic* hands of the Gargage Collector, you might run into a situation where they become scarce, which would make it impossible to create new channels.